# Setting socket options to reduce time delay between tcp segments

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking, tcpsocket

Im using socket to send data to remote. The data payload is ~4kB. Problem is tcp segments sent by tcp so slow (delay ~200-300ms each tcp segments). 
I tried with TCP_NODELAY (enabled), TCP_QUICKACK (enabled) and TCP_CORK(disabled) but cannot reduce the delayed time.
Here is my tcpdump, each 4kB data sent is divided into 3 tcp segments:
[image: tcpdump using my socket]

However, I saw a tcpdump by other application (which communicate with same remote). There is a very small or even no time delay between tcp segments.
[image: other app tcpdump]
Here is my code:

```
void createServerSocket() {
    int serverSockFd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    std::string address = "fd53:7cb8:383:5::73";
    int port = 42519;

    if (serverSockFd < 0)
    {
        printf("Create Server socket fail");
        return;
    }
    struct sockaddr_in6 serverAddress;
    (void)memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));
    serverAddress.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    serverAddress.sin6_port = htons(port);
    int result = inet_pton(AF_INET6, address.c_str(), &serverAddress.sin6_addr);

    if (result <= 0)
    {
        printf("inet_pton() failed portnumber: %d, address: %s \n", port, address.c_str());
        return;
    }

    // setting socket options
    int flag = 1;

    if(setsockopt(serverSockFd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_QUICKACK  ,(char *)&flag,sizeof(flag)) == -1)
    {
        printf("setsockopt TCP_QUICKACK failed for server socket on address %s \n", address.c_str());
    }
    if(setsockopt(serverSockFd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_CORK,(char *)&flag,sizeof(flag)) == -1)
    {
        printf("setsockopt TCP_CORK failed for server socket on address %s \n", address.c_str());
    }
    if(setsockopt(serverSockFd,IPPROTO_TCP,TCP_NODELAY,(char *)&flag,sizeof(flag)) == -1)
    {
        printf("setsockopt TCP_NODELAY failed for server socket on address %s \n", address.c_str());
    }

    result = bind(serverSockFd, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));

    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("bind() failed portnumber: %d, address: %s \n", port, address.c_str());
        return ;
    }

    result = listen(serverSockFd, 10);
    if (result != 0) {
        printf("listen() failed portnumber: %d, address: %s \n", port, address.c_str());
        return ;
    }

    acceptConnect(serverSockFd);
}

void acceptConnect(int serverSock)
{
    struct sockaddr_in6 clientAddress;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);
    memset(&clientAddress, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in6));

    const int clientSocket = accept(serverSock, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddress, &len);

    if(clientSocket >= 0) {
        char str_addr[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(clientAddress.sin6_addr),
                  str_addr, sizeof(str_addr));
        printf("New connection from: %s:%d ...\n", str_addr, ntohs(clientAddress.sin6_port));
        receiveDataFromSocket(clientSocket);
    }
}

void receiveDataFromSocket(int socket)
{
    int SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE = 8*1024;

    char buffer[SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE];
    memset(buffer, '\0', SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE);
    //Receive data from sock
    while (true) {
        int dataLen = recv(socket, buffer, SOCKET_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE, 0);
        printf("Receive data from socket: %d, msgLength = %d\n", socket, dataLen);
        sendDataOverSocket(socket);
    }
}

void sendDataOverSocket(int clientSock)
{
    int dataLen = 4*1024 + 7;
    char *buf = new char[dataLen];
    memset(buf, 'a', 4*1024 + 7);
    int ret;
    ret = send(clientSock, buf, dataLen, 0);

    if (ret <= 0) {
        printf("ERROR Send message over socket");
        return;
    }

    int error_code;
    socklen_t error_code_size = sizeof(sockaddr_in6);
    getsockopt(clientSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error_code, &error_code_size);
    printf("Error code size: %d, error code: %d\n", error_code_size, error_code);
}
```

Does my socket not setting enough to achive tcpdump in second picture?

Comment: Why are you setting `TCP_CORK`?  That will cause transmission of less-than-full segments to be delayed for up to 200ms, which is exactly the patten you're seeing.  Get rid of the `TCP_CORK` setting and see if that helps.  Get rid of `TCP_QUICKACK` too, it's not going to help.  `TCP_NODELAY` is the only option you need if you want less-than-full segments to be sent quickly.

Answer (score -2):

I thing you are sending too few data evey time.
trying this , in "void sendDataOverSocket(int clientSock)" function, change the sending buffer:
int dataLen = 4*1024 + 7;  ===> to a bigger number. 
then try it.